# Firebase retrieving data Error

Tags: android, firebase, android-database

I am trying to retrieve data from firebase to a listview...However there is one line of code that crashes the app, 
**mDatabase.addValueEventListener((com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener) listener);**

the crash report is **android addvalueeventlistener cannot be cast to com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener**

I have no idea on how to solve this anyone please:

package com.example.moses.mcn;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot;
import com.firebase.client.FirebaseError;
import com.firebase.client.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;

public class Business extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ListView business;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_business);
    }

    public ArrayList<String> arr;
    public ArrayAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        arr = new ArrayList<>();

        ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                map2list((Map) dataSnapshot.getValue());
                //formats the datasnapshot entries to strings
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                //makes the ListView realtime
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }


            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                // Getting Post failed, log a message
                System.out.println(databaseError.toException());
                // ...
            }
        };
        mDatabase.addValueEventListener((com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener) listener);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, arr);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.business);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);


    }

    public void map2list(Map<String,Long> map){

        arr.clear();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Long> entry : map.entrySet()) {

            Long key = Long.parseLong(entry.getKey());
            String d = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(key);
            Long value = entry.getValue();
            arr.add(d + ": " + value);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please show your build.gradle.  It seems you're using both the current Firebase database library and a legacy library - they are not compatible with each other.

Answer (score 0):

change the import to

```
 import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener
```

from

```
import com.firebase.client.ValueEventListener
```